# Is it possible to configure Quartz RAMJobStore and JDBCJobStore in single java application

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am creating a quartz java program with simple trigger using JDBCJobStore, my requirement is to process a method with the dynamic value entered by the user everytime by scheduling it with user specified given time and date which is also obtained from the user interface screen.

```
eg: public void execteMe(String name, int age, Date dob) {
       system.out.println("Name:"+name+" age:"+age+" DOB:"+dob);
    }
```

I am new to quartz scheduling. I know how to do this with RAMJobStore, but JDBCJobStore very new to me, someone please help me with your examples for me to proceed further. And also I would like to know whether it is possible to use RAMJobStore and JDBCJobStrore in single java application.

Comment: I have written a blog post on Quartz that uses a REST API to schedule jobs and uses liquibase to manage database migrations.    http://juliuskrah.com/tutorial/2017/10/06/persisting-dynamic-jobs-with-quartz-and-spring/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have multiple schedulers in a single Java application. Here is the [link](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/cookbook/MultipleSchedulers) explaining how to do that.